# How do I use an HTML text box value as a JavaScript parameter or variable and call the JavaScript Function with the text box value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function that works on its own, however, I am having difficulty getting it to function correctly inside of an HTML web page (no server backend). The function that works correctly by itself is:

```js
function decodeUrlDefensev3(link) {
  var matches = link.match(new RegExp('v3/__(.+?)__;(.*?)!'))

  // love me a mutable array
  var decode_pile = Array.from(matches[1]);
  var chars_pile = Array.from(atob(matches[2])).reverse();

  for (var match of link.matchAll(/\*/g)) {
    decode_pile[match.index] = match.pop()
  }

  return decode_pile.join('')
}

var link = "https://urldefense.com/v3/__https://files.bitsight.com/e3t/Ctc/LR*113/c1NcF04/VWyThK1lvg49W724nRX2d04lQW1xTZ7Q4QfX7gN6fpSV75nCTJV3Zsc37CgZP4N95fbTLz6L-gW48j6gR3bC3zwW6L_GnH7kDhzMW9418Rb3hJ605W2HjF587SWBXyW8RmYtF6fgdWYW5XQmQn1bFttzW5qPlhD5h_TCqW4-gDCr8x7fD0N4M_DVGdxFD9W2T0jhF4j9YsWW7603Qw8dF3j7W36QBsz4RM6hNW6Hpcdy8Qtmw4W8y5VBz2TLWGhVTNFr45gN7FDW7m9S0M1tvjXNW7vLHnj2945hZW437Z0x5Vd_ZcW7MjgJC89gYB6W2Y3sH14zDDZvW39S6bT1pFgM2W8gn9pV4HdltbW3MTVMS59VlW-VBQkF74S69PWW5yn7jz6PhmVLW4sYpYl4yDVH4W3dkf3v6S141VW3Sqpcn7xkSPcW33N24p3R1FxPW3y04W03TWHN4N2wvRyC4j7X83p5G1__;Kw!!HhY5bxTJhQ!vdj_DUrp0JIWgTw61Vg8M1chEvhp0k7XlLFiomq0Wu1rCrze9dzn2inIIVKchdRRP6HqJshCEuIHCbwCa1ha0FPyFA$"

console.log(decodeUrlDefensev3(link))
```

Expected output:

```
https://files.bitsight.com/e3t/Ctc/LR*113/c1NcF04/VWyThK1lvg49W72*nRX2d04lQW1xTZ7Q4QfX7gN6fpSV75nCTJV3Zsc37CgZP4N95fbTLz6L-gW48j6gR3bC3zwW6L_GnH7kDhzMW9418Rb3hJ605W2HjF587SWBXyW8RmYtF6fgdWYW5XQmQn1bFttzW5qPlhD5h_TCqW4-gDCr8x7fD0N4M_DVGdxFD9W2T0jhF4j9YsWW7603Qw8dF3j7W36QBsz4RM6hNW6Hpcdy8Qtmw4W8y5VBz2TLWGhVTNFr45gN7FDW7m9S0M1tvjXNW7vLHnj2945hZW437Z0x5Vd_ZcW7MjgJC89gYB6W2Y3sH14zDDZvW39S6bT1pFgM2W8gn9pV4HdltbW3MTVMS59VlW-VBQkF74S69PWW5yn7jz6PhmVLW4sYpYl4yDVH4W3dkf3v6S141VW3Sqpcn7xkSPcW33N24p3R1FxPW3y04W03TWHN4N2wvRyC4j7X83p5G1
```

The above code will return a correctly decoded website URL in the console. This works for technical people however, I am trying to create a basic HTML with a text box for users to enter the encoded URL, click a button, then return the decoded URL on their screen.

Using the below code:

```js
function decodeUrlDefensev3(link) {
  var matches = link.match(new RegExp('v3/__(.+?)__;(.*?)!'))

  // love me a mutable array
  var decode_pile = Array.from(matches[1]);
  var chars_pile = Array.from(atob(matches[2])).reverse();

  for (var match of link.matchAll(/\*/g)) {
    decode_pile[match.index] = match.pop()
  }

  return decode_pile.join('')
}

var link = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;

console.log(link)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox1" value="https://www.google.com" />
<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="decodeUrlDefensev3(link)" />
<input type="button" value="button2" onclick="function2()" />
```

The console.log(link) returns the true variable saved above. However, when I click the button, I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')".

How do I pass the textbox input and properly call my function so that whatever is entered inside of textbox1 is parsed using my JavaScript function?

An example of what I am trying to do can be found here:https://jsfiddle.net/37phxda8/1/

I need to use my function above, not the function on that JS Fiddle.

Comment: Please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and add a [mcve] with relevant input and expected output. Your `<enter some URL here to be parsed>` is not useful

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. I'm new to Stack Overflow and I'll remember that for future questions.

Comment: I clicked the button looking like this `[<>]` and pasted the code into the relevant panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing the parameter to the decodeurl function. Try it like this:

```
function decodeUrlDefensev3(link) {
    var matches = link.match(new RegExp('v3/__(.+?)__;(.*?)!'))

    // love me a mutable array
    var decode_pile = Array.from(matches[1]);
    var chars_pile = Array.from(atob(matches[2])).reverse();
    
    for (var match of link.matchAll(/\*/g)) {
        decode_pile[match.index] = match.pop()
    }

    return decode_pile.join('')
}

function handleClick() {
   var link = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
   decodeUrlDefensev3(link);
}
```

Then in your html:

```
<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="handleClick()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the help on this, it makes sense to me. I'm still learning, and this has helped a lot. Have a good weekend.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because there are no results from the `link.match` function (for "https://www.google.com"), let alone 3 [2nd and 3rd items of the result are used for `decode_pile` and `chars_pile` respectively]. You should either change the `RegExp` for the match or provide and error message like the commented `if` block in the edited code below.

Also, your function is not taking updated input from *textbox1* - only the initial value of "https://www.google.com" set in html. You should retrieve it within the function like:

```
function decodeUrlDefensev3() {
    var link = document.getElementById('textbox1').value;
    var matches = link.match(new RegExp('v3/__(.+?)__;(.*?)!'))
    
    /*if (!matches || matches.length < 3) {
        alert("Invalid input, could not decode");
        return null;
    }*/

    // love me a mutable array
    var decode_pile = Array.from(matches[1]);
    var chars_pile = Array.from(atob(matches[2])).reverse();
    
    for (var match of link.matchAll(/\*/g)) {
        decode_pile[match.index] = match.pop()
    }

    return decode_pile.join('')
}
```

And then your HTML for the button can simply be:

```
<input type="button" value="button1" onclick="decodeUrlDefensev3()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing up the error handling, this was not making any sense to me.  Now that you included the error handling, it makes more sense. Now I just wish I could figure out how to return the URL even if it is an error. Have a good weekend!

Comment: @GregoryCarlton just `return link` instead of `return null` inside the error-handling if block, but it will return the un-decoded url from the input.